# Why are some .bat files "run as an administrator" bold in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, batch-file, context-menu, runas

When I right click on some `.bat` files the "run as administrator" selection is **bold**. Why is this?

How do I make it so that **all** `.bat` files act that way too?

Comment: Are you talking about in the right-click context menu? Bold usually means that's the default option if you double-click on the file.

Comment: @DarthAndroid yup the right-click context menu, how do i make other `.bat` files behave the same way?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the names of the .BAT files that do and don't have the bold Run as administrator option?

Comment: @Twisty thanks for replying, the files i have are shortcuts of files that i created, so i don't think naming is the issue here :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer 1:

Individual `.BAT` files can be configured to always **Run as administrator** by creating a shortcut to the batch file and modifying the shortcut's properties.  Here's how:

1. Create a shortcut to the batch file
2. **Right-click** the shortcut and choose **Properties**
3. On the *Shortcut* tab click **Advanced**
   [image]
4. Select the **Run as administrator** checkbox
   [image]
5. Click **OK** twice to save and exit

---

### Answer 2:

The solution above is great if you don't mind all the extra steps.  But why work so hard?  **You can configure *all* `.BAT` files to default to the *Run as administrator* option**. It only requires a simple registry edit:

1. Save the following code snippet into a file named `DefaultToRunas.reg`

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell]
   @="runas"
   ```
2. **Double-click** the `DefaultToRunas.reg` file to merge the settings into the Windows Registry
3. Click **Yes** if prompted by UAC
4. Click **Yes** to merge the changes into the Registry

   **Notes:**

   - I've confirmed this works on Windows 7, Windows 8 and Server 2008 R2
   - This setting change affects all users of the computer

#### What About Other File Types?

You can use this registry edit to change the default for other file types as well.  For example, to make **Run as administrator** the default action for command files (`.CMD`), substitute the following registry file in Step 1 above:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell]
    @="runas"
```

You can read more about manipulating the Windows Context menu in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply! I guess I didn't look through all the tabs in the context menu enough before

Comment: You're welcome.  Figuring out how to get one batch script to run as admin was easy.  It took me several hours to find out how to make _all_ batch files always run as Administrator. Thanks for the challenging question!